# Floating objects help in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

I hope someone can help me. I am having trouble getting the .car objects to float. I have 6 .car objects, and I want to place them in 2 rows with 3 objects per row. When I do manage to get the objects to float, they end up being compressed on the LHS. Here is the code:

```css
#cars {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.car img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.car {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.car:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.car p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.car-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: #777;
}

#cars a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="cars">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="compact_car.html">
          <img alt="compact car" src="compact-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Compact Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Great for city driving and easy parking. Fuel-efficient and affordable.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="sedan_car.html">
          <img alt="sedan car" src="sedan-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Sedan Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Spacious and comfortable, perfect for families or long road trips.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="suv_car.html">
          <img alt="suv car" src="suv-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>SUV Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Rugged and versatile, ideal for off-road adventures and outdoor activities.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="sports_car.html">
          <img alt="sports car" src="sports-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Sports Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="luxury_car.html">
          <img alt="luxury car" src="luxury-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Luxury Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="electric_car.html">
          <img alt="electric car" src="electric-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Electric Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried using float, display: inline-block, flex. I have even placed each object within a  tag (as shown in the code).

I cannot seem to get it to work!

Comment: float is useful when you really do want an object (often an image) to 'float' in the sense that the surrounding text will go around it, underneath as well as to the side if required. However, nowadays CSS offers better ways when you don't want this but want to layout in columns and rows. For your situation look at using grid which is a 2 dimensional layout styling unlike flex which is one dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do if you want a 3 column layout is to use grid, particularly the `grid-template-rows` property. CSS tricks has a good [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) on grid and there's a decent explainer [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU) by Kevin Powell on youtube to get you started. No one really uses floats anymore for layout.

Marked up code below:

```css
/* added this */
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  
  /* some layout tweaks below */
  width: fit-content; /* make the width of the container the same as the content so we can... */
  margin-inline: auto; /* ...put the block in the centre of the viewport. */
  
  gap: 0.25rem; /* optional: if we want to add a bit of space between each container-wrapper div, we add a gap */
}

#cars {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-wrapper {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 300px;
}

.car img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.car {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.car:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.car p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.car-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: #777;
}

#cars a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="cars">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="compact_car.html">
          <img alt="compact car" src="compact-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Compact Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Great for city driving and easy parking. Fuel-efficient and affordable.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="sedan_car.html">
          <img alt="sedan car" src="sedan-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Sedan Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Spacious and comfortable, perfect for families or long road trips.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="suv_car.html">
          <img alt="suv car" src="suv-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>SUV Car</p>
        <p class="car-description">Rugged and versatile, ideal for off-road adventures and outdoor activities.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="sports_car.html">
          <img alt="sports car" src="sports-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Sports Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="luxury_car.html">
          <img alt="luxury car" src="luxury-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Luxury Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="car">
        <a href="electric_car.html">
          <img alt="electric car" src="electric-car.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>Electric Car</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If I use the grid template it would affect my whole page :/

Comment: Nope. Just the child elements

Answer (score 0):

change the .container-wrapper width to 33% it will work fine.

```
 .container-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
```

Comment: I had tried using % but the .car objects do inline with each other, but they are compressed on the LHS of the page. I cannot understand why!

Comment: I edit the answer. 33*3=99, if you change it to 33.3% it works fine.

Comment: and if you want to add gaps on the left and right of the page you can add padding to the .container element or add max-width for it too.